# Trouble accessing FTP internally

Tags: ftp, virtualhost, mac-osx-server, hosts

I am currently running OS X Server 4. I have multiple websites (virtual hosts) set up with it. Lets call them `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.

Internally, they are both being run off of the same IP. Let's say `192.168.0.5`.

When I try to access the ftp server for `domain1.com`, sometimes I get the files for `domain2.com`, and vice versa.

However, this only occurs internally. When I access the servers from their domain name on an external internet connection, the FTP connection will always go to the correct server.

The `host` file on my client that is accessing the FTP connection has:

```
192.168.0.5     domain1.com
192.168.0.5     domain2.com
```

That allows me to connect internally to my websites. Is there something else I have to add to the `hosts` file in order to connect properly to the right site? As it is currently, it is a crapshoot whether or not I can edit my files from another machine on the same network.

Comment: What do your internal DNS records look like? Perhaps DNS is being used instead of hosts entries internally.

Comment: What is your ftp server config? Really, the destination you get with an ftp service will depend on the home directory of the user that logs in. If both DNS records point to the same host, then it doesn't matter which one you use, they are getting to the same place.